# exporting environment variable using .sh file

Tags: 16.04, environment-variables, sh

so I have create `setup.sh` file like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
export SP_TWITTER_KEY=adsfad
export SP_TWITTER_SECRET=aadsfadsf
export SP_TWITTER_ACCESSTOKEN=asdfasdfa
export SP_TWITTER_ACCESSSECRET=asdfasdfas

export mongo_connection=localhost
```

and after that I run this command in order to turn the file to be executable :

```
$ chmod +x setup.sh
```

finally execute the file so that all my env varible are exported. I have tried several ways like this :

```
$ . /setup.sh
$ .setup.sh
$ bash setup.sh
```

But none of them are working, because I check again the variable like `mongo_connection` and others are still empty. Any idea what's wrong or am I missing something?

NOTE : I'm using tmux to run my shell terminal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without any change into your script you can simply run in like this:

```
. setup.sh
```

or

```
source setup.sh
```

it will cause your variables to be set in the current shell otherwise bash will open a non-interactive shell, runs your command into that and after it's finish, it closes that shell.

for more explanation, `help source`:

> source: source FILENAME
>   Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
>   Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.

Comment: it looks like my problem is when I execute my `setup.sh` in another shell on tmux. It doesnt export on the other shell

Comment: When you export a variable it will only be available in child process of that shell not others, if you want to set something globally you can put it in places like `.bashrc` .