# How to read strings from a file to use them in another file as a string

Tags: command-line, bash

I am in trouble reading a string from a file into another script as a string.
Here is my detail:

I have 2 script file: one is 'step0.sh' and the other is 'step1.lsf'

'step0.sh' file contains only two lines

```
DIR="/sc/arion/work/kimm61/vepSIMUL/clinvar"
IN="clinvar.vcf"
```

and 'step1.lsf' contains those lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J step1_1
#BSUB -P acc_Itan_lab
#BSUB -q private
#BSUB -n 41
#BSUB -R rusage[mem=20000]
#BSUB -R span[hosts=1]
#BSUB -W 120:00
#BSUB -o echo $DIR/step1out/%J.stdout
#BSUB -eo echo $DIR/step1out/%J.stderr
#BSUB -L /bin/bash


cd /sc/arion/work/kimm61/vepSIMUL/clinvar/
mkdir step1out


source activate phen
ml bcftools/1.10.2
module load vep/100

source /sc/arion/work/kimm61/vepSIMUL/clinvar/step0.sh
directory=echo "$DIR"
input=echo "$IN"
WRKDIR=echo "$DIR"/step1out
ref_fasta=/sc/arion/projects/Itan_lab/vep_data/fasta_ref/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.primary_assembly.fa.gz

myinput=echo "$DIR"/"$IN"
myoutput=vep1_1.vcf
```

(What I want)

1. for the directory from 'step1.lsf', I would like to read 'DIR' from 'step0.sh'
2. for the input from 'step1.lsf', I would like to read 'IN' from 'step0.sh'
3. for the standard output(-o) and the standard err output(-eo), I would like to read'DIR' from 'step0.sh'

Comment: Since the lines of `step1.lsf` appear to be syntactically correct POSIX variable assignments, you could simply source that file into you script. See for example [exporting environment variable using .sh file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917340/exporting-environment-variable-using-sh-file)

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: What's not working? You're already sourcing the file as far as I can see? Also, please include the scripts as text and not as images. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are showing in the images as code-formatted text. Then delete the images.

Answer (score 2):

The proper and most simple way is to source the *settings* file in the beginning of the *script*. Then use the variables like as they were defined in the *script*. For Dash/Sh you must use the command `.`, for Bash you can use either `source` or `.`.

```bash
cat step1.lsf
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

. step0.sh

echo "$DIR"
echo "$IN"
```

---

If for some reason this is not that you want, you could parse the values of the variables from the *settings* file, capture the output by a command substitution `$()` and assign them to variables within the *script*. For example.

```bash
cat step1.lsf
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$(sed -nr 's/^DIR="(.*)"$/\1/p' step0.sh)"
IN="$(sed -nr 's/^IN="(.*)"$/\1/p' step0.sh)"

echo "$DIR"
echo "$IN"
```

- Here is [an explanation](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097891/566421) about the `sed`'s options in use.

---

Actually the problem in your script are the assignments like this:

```bash
directory=echo "$DIR"
```

Here you need to use command substitution to make it work.

```bash
directory="$(echo "$DIR")"
```

But in this case (where you are not processing the value in some special way) you can just assign the value of the variable `$DIR` to the other variable.

```bash
directory="$DIR"
```